# Grep multiple patterns and print pattern and its previous lines

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file with data

```
cell A
function (A1A2)
Next state
Test cell
Type combinational 
(CO)
output
(A1)
input
(A2)
input
cell X
function ((A1+A2)B)
Hold rising 
Type combinational 
Min_pulse_width
(Z)
output
(A1)
input
(A2)
input
(B)
input
```

I want output as

```
cell A
function (A1A2)
Type combinational 
(CO)
output
(A1)
input
(A2)
input
cell X
function ((A1+A2)B)
Type combinational 
(Z)
output
(A1)
input
(A2)
input
(B)
input
```

The input file has multiple lines above shown format with many parameters present.
But from that file I only want to `grep cell, function, type, output and its previous line , input and its previous line` .

I can grep `cell, function, type`using

```
grep "cell|function|type" file
```

and can grep `output and its previous line and input  And it's previous line as`

```
awk '/input/{print x;print};{x=$0}' file

awk '/output/{print x;print};{x=$0}' file
```

But how can I do above 3 steps together and get shown output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this `awk`:

```sh
awk '/^(in|out)put/{print p; print} /^(cell|function|Type)/; {p = $0}' file

cell A
function (A1A2)
Type combinational
(CO)
output
(A1)
input
(A2)
input
cell X
function ((A1+A2)B)
Type combinational
(Z)
output
(A1)
input
(A2)
input
(B)
input
```

Comment: I tried this, I am getting cell function type correctly but I unable to get input and output

Comment: You can see `input` and `output` lines in output shown. May be try: `awk '/^(in|out)put/{print p; print} /^(cell|function|Type)/; {p = $0}' file`

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -Ev '(Next state)|(Test cell)|(Hold rising)|(Min_pulse_width)' file
```

Use -E to enable regular expressions and -v for inverse searching. Then state the terms you DON'T want to search for.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nE 'N;/^(cell|function|Type)/P;/\n(output|input)/p;D' file
```

Turn off implicit printing `-n` and on easier regexp `-E`.

Open a two line window.

Print the required strings using pattern matching.

Delete everything and repeat.